# Remove click in the middle of the message screen in pywhatkit

Tags: python, whatsapp

Can anybody help me.

When using sendwhats_image, before starting to type the text, he clicks in the middle of the screen. When entering the code, on line 135, there is no field that informs about this click, but looking at line 30, there is a pg.click(core.WIDTH / 2, core.HEIGHT / 2) but, even removing this line, the click still remains. I don't know where I can block this click, or change position.

My Code:

```
# Enviar Print Report PV MT - 
imgreportPvMT ='C:/Users/Corporativo/Documents/Bot Alphard/reportPVMT.png'
kt.sendwhats_image("+5561xxxxxxxx",imgreportPvMT,"José Artur - Report Pós Vendas",15,True)
time.sleep(10)
```

when I click on control and on top of sendwhats_image  , so I can see the code, I don't find anything that refers to the click on the screen. There is a pg.click(core.WIDTH / 2, core.HEIGHT / 2) on line 30, but it refers to sendwhatmsg_instantly

```
def sendwhats_image(
    receiver: str,
    img_path: str,
    caption: str = "",
    wait_time: int = 15,
    tab_close: bool = False,
    close_time: int = 4,
    
) -> None:
    """Send Image to a WhatsApp Contact or Group at a Certain Time"""

    if (not receiver.isalnum()) and (not core.check_number(number=receiver)):
        raise exceptions.CountryCodeException("Country Code Missing in Phone Number!")

    current_time = time.localtime()
    core.send_image(
        path=img_path, caption=caption, receiver=receiver, wait_time=wait_time
    )
    log.log_image(_time=current_time, path=img_path, receiver=receiver, caption=caption)
    if tab_close:
        core.close_tab(wait_time=close_time)
```

I tried taking the code at line 30, pg.click(core.WIDTH / 2, core.HEIGHT / 2) on line 30, but it refers to sendwhatmsg_instantly

Answer (score 0):

You need to open whats.py file and comment line 30:

#pg.click(core.WIDTH / 2, core.HEIGHT / 2)

Also, core.py and comment line 121:

#click(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)

I did it and it worked for me, sending Messages Instantaneoulsy and Images